# Is there a way to compare two richtextboxs text and highlight the deference?

Tags: c#, comparison, compare, richtextbox, highlighting

I have two richtextbox's that display stored procedures and its previous version.

I would like to know if i could compare the two and highlight the differences?

It would be similar to the notepad++ compare plugin.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you need this as part of a program that you are writing or just a dev tool for you to use?

Comment: I'd recommend [the google diff (lib)](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) for diffing the texts, and then taking the output and putting it an another textbox :D The library has functionality similar to the diff *nix command. If you need a more explicit example, just holler and maybe I'll write something up.

Comment: @tgolisch I need it as part of a program.

Comment: @flindeber Hey thanks ill check it out. :) Thanks good link +1

Comment: @flindeberg Hey man there is some Copyright i can't use this.

Comment: @Pomster It is released under [the apache license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License), is that too harsh or do you need it to be _"completely"_ free? Ie you can use apache licensed code in your own projects as long as it is released under a more strict or equal license. [This small _FAQ_](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN) may make stuff a bit clearer.

Comment: @flindeberg No i saw this license is fine :). You have been a great help man :D write something i can give you and answer for, because you already answerd my question in a comment :P

Comment: Comment 2 is the answer :) check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10926686/1356321

Comment: @Pomster Copied my text into an answer, I'm glad I could help :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend the [google diff (lib)](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) for diffing the texts, and then taking the output and putting it in an another textbox :D

The library has functionality similar to the diff *nix command. It is also released under the apache 2.0 license, which is [described here](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN) and in short means that it can be used in any type of project except if the end result is supposed to be release as "free" software, for example GPL 3.0.